# How can I pass a build setting to a genrule in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Suppose I have a simple `genrule` like this:

```
genrule(
  name = "fruit",
  outs = [ "fruit.txt" ],
  cmd = "echo \"apple\" > $@",
)
```

Now I want to make this configurable from the outside.

I can use `action_env` like this:

```
genrule(
  name = "fruit",
  outs = [ "fruit.txt" ],
  cmd = "echo \"$$FRUIT\" > $@",
)
```

```bash
bazel build --action_env=FRUIT=banana //:fruit
```

However, I don't want to use `action_env` because it affects all rules and it is bad for caching.

There is [`--define`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--define), but the docs describe it as legacy:

> --define is an alternative legacy syntax for custom flags (for example --define foo=bar). This can be expressed either in the values attribute (values = {"define": "foo=bar"}) or the define_values attribute (define_values = {"foo": "bar"}). --define is only supported for backwards compatibility. Prefer Starlark build settings whenever possible.

So that leaves build settings.

However, it is not clear how to get the value of a build setting into my `genrule`.

Something like this:

```
# Not real code 

config_setting(
  name = "fruit",
)

genrule(
  name = "fruit",
  outs = [ "fruit.txt" ],
  cmd = "echo \"$(value :fruit)\" > $@",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `genrule` can't read build settings, so you'll need a little Starlark rule to read the setting and create an action with the information in the setting:

`WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "66ffd9315665bfaafc96b52278f57c7e2dd09f5ede279ea6d39b2be471e7e3aa",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.4.2/bazel-skylib-1.4.2.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.4.2/bazel-skylib-1.4.2.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")

bazel_skylib_workspace()
```

`defs.bzl`

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:common_settings.bzl", "BuildSettingInfo")

def _fruit_impl(ctx):
  fruit = ctx.attr._fruit[BuildSettingInfo].value
  out = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".txt")
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
    outputs = [out],
    command = 'echo "the fruit is $1" > $2',
    arguments = [fruit, out.path],
  )
  return DefaultInfo(files = depset([out]))

fruit_library = rule(
  implementation = _fruit_impl,
  attrs = {
    "_fruit": attr.label(default = "//:fruit"),
  },
)
```

`BUILD`

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:common_settings.bzl", "string_flag")
load(":defs.bzl", "fruit_library")

string_flag(
    name = "fruit",
    build_setting_default = "apple",
)

fruit_library(
  name = "fruit_lib",
)
```

```
$ bazel build fruit_lib
INFO: Analyzed target //:fruit_lib (4 packages loaded, 7 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:fruit_lib up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/fruit_lib.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.553s, Critical Path: 0.02s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions

$ cat bazel-bin/fruit_lib.txt
the fruit is apple

$ bazel build fruit_lib --//:fruit=strawberry
INFO: Build option --//:fruit has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //:fruit_lib (0 packages loaded, 7 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:fruit_lib up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/fruit_lib.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.184s, Critical Path: 0.03s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions

$ cat bazel-bin/fruit_lib.txt
the fruit is strawberry
```